# How to view the SQL Server stored procedure from linked server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

Anyone has the idea how to get this through?

I have a production and a test server. I created a linked server of production on the test server machine. I can do all DML that affects the production server from the test server, but I cannot see the stored procedure object of the production server on the test server.

RPC and RPC Out is already True.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you.
Using sp_HelpText you get entire SP text.

```
EXEC [ServerName].[DatabaseName].dbo.sp_HelpText 'SPName'
```

Comment: Actually I wish it could be the same view in the actual Server where in I can see the stored procedure object for the reason that it is very easy for visual purpose. Anyway, if there is no way, I have to use the sp_HelpText built in SP.